# MacOS " error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Tags: c, macos, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile my program P2.c but this error pops up and I don't even know where to start:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file P2, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-unsupported file format ( 0x23 0x69 0x6E 0x63 0x6C 0x75 0x64 0x65 0x20 0x3C 0x73 0x74 0x64 0x69 0x6F 0x2E )
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm providing 'brew list' in case it is useful:

```
% brew list
==> Formulae
ca-certificates         gdbm                    harfbuzz                libtiff                 lua                     pkg-config              xz
cairo                   gettext                 icu4c                   libx11                  lzo                     python@3.9
cython                  giflib                  jpeg                    libxau                  mpdecimal               qt@5
fontconfig              glib                    libcerf                 libxcb                  openssl@1.1             readline
freetype                gnuplot                 libffi                  libxdmcp                pango                   sqlite
fribidi                 gobject-introspection   libpng                  libxext                 pcre                    webp
gd                      graphite2               libpthread-stubs        libxrender              pixman                  xorgproto
```

Someone recommended to remove 'binutils' but I don't have it installed, or to change the $PATH variable but I don't know what is he referring to;

```
% which ranlib
/usr/bin/ranlib
% $(which ranlib) -V
Apple Inc. version cctools-986
error: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib: no archives specified
Usage: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib [-sactfqLT] [-] archive [...]
```

I just want to compile and debug my P2.c, help :(

this is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

// Avaluar funcions: 1) f(x,y) ; 2) d/dx f(x,y) ; 3) d/dy f(x,y)
double f(double, double, double, double, double, double);
double fx(double, double, double, double, double, double);
double fy(double, double, double, double, double, double);
// 4) Predicció:
void p(double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double);
// 5) Correcció:
void c(double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double);
// 6) Main:
int main()
{
    double A = -0.8, B = 0.5, C = -1.2, D = 0.3;
    int n = 100000;
    double h = 1e-2;
    double pre = 1e-8;
    int iterMax = 5;
    double tol = 1e-6;
    char outputfile[30];
    FILE *fout;
    printf("Donem el nom del fitxer de sortda\n");
    scanf("%s", outputfile);
    fout = fopen(outputfile, "w");
    if (fout == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error al obrir %s\n", outputfile);
        exit(1);
    }
    // // Inicialitzem (x0, y0). He trobat els punts inicials mitjançant el programa:
    double x0 = 0.994910, y0 = 1.005750;
    double x = x0, y = y0;
    // Comprovem que son bons:
    if (abs(f(x, y, A, B, C, D)) > pre)
        return -1;

    return 0;

    // Imprimim el primer punt
    fprintf(fout, "%f\t %f\n", x, y);
    // Ara podem fer la continuació de la corba a partir d'aquest punt:
    printf("Imprimint primer sentit...");
    for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++)
    {
        // Fem la predicció
        p(x, y, h, 1, A, B, C, D);
        // Fem la comprovació de punts singulars:
        if (sqrt(pow(fx(x, y, A, B, C, D), 2) + pow(fy(x, y, A, B, C, D), 2)) < tol)
        {
            printf("Som molt a prop d'un punt singular!");
            return -4;
        }
        // Fem la correcció
        c(x, y, x0, y0, h, iterMax, pre, A, B, C, D);
        // Imprimim el punt
        fprintf(fout, "%f\t %f\n", x, y);
    }
    printf("Primer sentit imprès!");
    // Omplim els punts cap a l'altre sentit
    printf("Imprimint segon sentit...");
    x = x0;
    y = y0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++)
    {
        // Fem la predicció
        p(x, y, h, -1, A, B, C, D);
        // Fem la comprovació de punts singulars:
        if (sqrt(pow(fx(x, y, A, B, C, D), 2) + pow(fy(x, y, A, B, C, D), 2)) < tol)
        {
            printf("Som molt a prop d'un punt singular!");
            return -4;
        }
        // Fem la correcció
        c(x, y, x0, y0, h, iterMax, pre, A, B, C, D);
        // Imprimim el punt
        fprintf(fout, "%f\t %f\n", x, y);
    }
    printf("Segon sentit imprès!");
    printf("Procès completat!");
    return 0;
}

double f(double x, double y, double A, double B, double C, double D)
{
    return (16 * x * x * x * x + y * y * y * y + A * x * y * y - 16 * x * x * y - 1) * (x * x + (y - 1) * (y - 1) + B * x * y + C) + D;
}
double fx(double x, double y, double A, double B, double C, double D)
{
    return ((C + x * x + (-1 + y) * (-1 + y) + B * x * y) * (64 * x * x * x - 32 * x * y + A * y * y) + (2 * x + B * y) * (-1 + 16 * x * x * x * x - 16 * x * x * y + A * x * y * y + y * y * y * y));
}
double fy(double x, double y, double A, double B, double C, double D)
{
    return (2 * (C + x * x + (-1 + y) * (-1 + y) + B * x * y) * (-8 * x * x + A * x * y + 2 * y * y * y) + (-2 + B * x + 2 * y) * (-1 + 16 * x * x * x * x - 16 * x * x * y + A * x * y * y + y * y * y * y));
}
void p(double x, double y, double h, double sentit, double A, double B, double C, double D)
{
    // Calculem el gradient de f normalitzat i després trobem el tangent (u,v) ==tg==> (v, -u)
    double v[2] = {sentit * fy(x, y, A, B, C, D) / sqrt(pow(fx(x, y, A, B, C, D), 2) + pow(fy(x, y, A, B, C, D), 2)), -sentit * fx(x, y, A, B, C, D) / sqrt(pow(fx(x, y, A, B, C, D), 2) + pow(fy(x, y, A, B, C, D), 2))};
    // Ara trobem els nous x, y;
    x = x + h * v[0];
    y = y + h * v[1];
}
void c(double x, double y, double x0, double y0, double h, double iterMax, double pre, double A, double B, double C, double D)
{
    int iter = 0;
    // Volem resoldre el sistema utilitzant el metode de Newton:
    // Veiem si els punts verifiquen la precisió necessaria:
    while (fabs(f(x, y, A, B, C, D)) < pre)
    {

        if (iter >= iterMax)
        {
            exit(-2);
        }
        // Fem iteracions del mètode de Newton
        // v = v - DF-1(x)*F(x)
        double x1 = x;
        double detJ = fx(x, y, A, B, C, D) * 2 * (y - y0) - fy(x, y, A, B, C, D) * 2 * (x - x0);
        if (fabs(detJ) == 0)
            exit(-3);
        x = x - (1 / detJ) * (2 * (y - y0) * f(x, y, A, B, C, D) - fy(x, y, A, B, C, D) * (pow((x - x0), 2) + pow((y - y0), 2) - h * h));
        y = y - (1 / detJ) * (-2 * (x1 - x0) * f(x1, y, A, B, C, D) + fx(x1, y, A, B, C, D) * (pow((x1 - x0), 2) + pow((y - y0), 2) - h * h));
        iter++;
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How do you build your program? Please [edit] your question to show us the exact commands you use.

Comment: `unknown-unsupported file format` means the file P2 you are passing to the linker is not an object file built for your architecture.

Answer (score 2):

If we take a look at the hex-number sequence presented by the linker:

```
0x23 0x69 0x6E 0x63 0x6C 0x75 0x64 0x65 ...
```

That spells `#inbclude` in the ASCII alphabet.

That tells us that you're trying to link the source file directly, and not compiling it.

Since you're on a macOS system use the `clang` program to compile *and* link the source file:

```
clang P2.c -o P2
```

After this you should have a `P2` executable program in the directory, which you can then run:

```
./P2
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much!!! problem solved :)